# What does http-equiv default-style do?

Tags: html, css, meta-tags

What does `meta http-equiv=default-style` do?
Should I prefer this meta tag to the the default `link rel=stylesheet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, we could change the stylesheet we're using. But the http-equiv=default-style of the meta tag says that the value of the "content" attribute written in the same meta tag is the default stylesheet to use.

Read:

1. [MDN's explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)
2. [W3School's explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)
3. [GFG's explanation](https://www.bing.com/search?q=html%20meta%20tag%20http-equiv&qs=RI&pq=meta%20tag%20http&sc=1-13&cvid=458C199EC4B54C238D5488232B885D98&FORM=QBRE&sp=1&ghc=1)

Comment: please add external sources that confirm your statement (official docs etc)

Comment: Okay, but what does it mean the "default stylesheet". What does it replace? Will it just remove all other imported stylesheets?

Comment: No. It doesn't remove any style sheets, but it just sets the default one. It can always be replaced. Say, for example, your website has 2 stylesheets to use. One comes into action when you click the `dark theme` button, and another comes into action when you click the `light theme` button. You want your website to have the light theme by default. You can set a `light-theme.css` stylesheet as your default style sheet by using the http-equiv attribute.